# Particular solution to system of linear differential equations for singular system matrix

Tags: differential

I have a linear system on standard state space form

$\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t)$

I would like to find the solution to this, which usually is

$x(t) = e^{At}x(0) + \int\limits_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau$

Since, in my case, $u(t) = u$ is constant (but undetirmened) from $0$ to $t$, it can be moved outside the integral, and the integral can be computed symbolically

$x(t) = e^{At}x(0) + A^{-1}(e^{At} - I)Bu$

Now, unfortunately my $A$ matrix is singular, so the formula above can not be computed. I've tried doing a coordinate transformation, to no avail.

I also tried to expand the matrix exponential to remove the inverse

$A^{-1}(e^{At} - I)Bu = A^{-1}(I + At + \frac{A^2t^2}{2} + \frac{A^3t^3}{6} + \frac{A^4t^4}{24} + ... - I)Bu = (It + \frac{At^2}{2} + \frac{A^2t^3}{6} + \frac{A^3t^4}{24} + ...)Bu$

But since $A$ is singular, the exponentiation of it breaks down numerically.

Any ideas?

Comment: For clarity of exposition, you could just work with $\dot x(t)=Ax(t)+B.$

Comment: I'm going to use $u$ for some symbolic calculations later, so I don't want to omitt it. And removing $u$ makes no difference to the problem statement.